# How big is the LLVM and Clang source?

Tags: llvm

I'm currently living in a third-world country and my internet connection has a very limited monthly data allocation.  I'd like to download the LLVM and Clang source but not if it's huge.  Does anyone have a rough idea (e.g. nearest order of magnitude) how much data an SVN checkout of the source is likely to use?

Comment: http://llvm.org/releases/download.html - 3.0 LLVM source tarball is 10M, clang 7M. Test suite: >70M.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [LLVM webpage](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#svn):

> - [LLVM source code](http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/llvm-3.0.tar.gz) (9.9M)
> - [Clang source code](http://llvm.org/releases/3.0/clang-3.0.tar.gz) (6.9M)

Comment: Epic fail on my part.  I looked at the Clang pages and I could only find the instructions for downloading with svn.  Thank you.